# How to view arp -a "ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput" into DATAGRIDVIEW

Tags: c#, datagridview, cmd, mac-address, redirectstandardoutput

I have a small windows application which invokes command prompt and then assign the result to a richTextBox. I want to assign the results from command prompt "arp -a" to a datagridview. 
How can I do this.

here is the code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C  arp -a";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.Start();
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.Close();
        richTextBox1.Text = output;

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to "parse" the output for example like this:

```
// add columns to your grid (could also be done in designer)
dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(
    new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(),
    new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(), 
    new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());

while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    string[] values = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine().Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (values.Length == 3) dataGridView1.Rows.Add(values);
}
```